# Httpd + Expect Script Fail (no more ptys) if httpd is not run through cli

Tags: centos, httpd, expect

I have a CentOS virtual server through Vmware. The server runs an httpd daemon which serves an php page with a form. The users complete the form, and by clicking submit the php page calls an expect scripts. If i run the httpd throught the default init.d script i get a "no more ptys" error, but if i run httpd through root terminal the script runs without problems. How can i make the httpd run the expect scripts without having to run the httpd daemon by hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like `system('expect ...');`, I suggest you take a look at PHP's [native Expect support](http://www.php.net/manual/en/expect.examples-usage.php).  It handles the creation of a PTY, and is less of a mess than shelling out to other files, etc.

Comment: Thanx! I'm aware of the phps support for expect but in the current setup, i cannot recompile with it.Also the script runs flawlessly if the httpd daemon is run through ssh

Answer (score -1):

This exact same behavior was driving me crazy.  Disabling SELinux seems to have allowed me to work past this.  There's lots I don't know, so unfortunately, I can't offer more than that at this point.